# The activebackground button function in tkinter, python is not working for macOS Big Sur Version: 11.6

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()
window.title("Click Me")

click=tk.Button(window, text="Click Me", highlightbackground="blue", activebackground="red")
click.place(x=200,y=300)

window.mainloop()
```

It doesn't return any error to me. But, when I click on the button, nothing happens.
Please reply to me as soon as you can.

Comment: there is no button.  Need to add `click.pack()`. Furthermore, need to point to a function, something like `command = helloCallBack` where `helloCallBack()` is a function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Mac allows you to change the background or activebackground of buttons. Apple wants to control the look of standard controls.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. By the way, if that's how it is, do you know anything I can use in replace of the activebackground parameter?

Answer (score -1):

I have added two things to make this work:

1. a call back function `helloCallback`
2. pack the button properly so that it is visable.

here is the code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()
window.title("Click Me")

# a test function to execute when the button is clicked
def helloCallback():
    print('hi there, it works')
    return

click=tk.Button(window, text="Click Me", highlightbackground="blue", activebackground="red", command=helloCallback)

# pack the button
click.pack() 


window.mainloop()
```

**result**: when the button is pressed, it prints `hi there, it works` to the console.

Comment: This doesn't change the `activebackground` on OSX, which is what the question is asking about.